# How to use Perl to Backup Host file?

Tags: perl, copy, backup

I need to backup the host file before I run a program that changes it.

So I first delete the back up file in case it already exists and then copy the host file in the same directory with a new name.

I just need a full script to do this one task. I convert all Perl scripts to and EXE using Perl2EXE.

This is my code so far:

```
    #use Win32::OLE;
#use Win32::OLE qw(in);
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;
use File::Copy 'copy';

$APPNAME = "TEST_TOP_Install";
###############################################################################################################################
###### This section Creates a log file on machines being pushed
###### The location of the log file is c:\winnt\Install_logs or c:\windows\Install_logs
###############################################################################################################################

###### System Root Path 
$rootpath = $ENV{"systemroot"};
$alluserspath = $ENV{"ALLUSERSPROFILE"};
$programfilespath = $ENV{"PROGRAMFILES"};
$SystemDrive = $ENV{"SystemDrive"};  # c:
$WIN32DIR = "$SystemDrive\\program files\(x86\)";

$LOGDIR = "$rootpath\\install_logs" ;
if (!-e $LOGDIR) {
    $DIR = `mkdir $LOGDIR`;
    }

open ($APPNAME, ">$rootpath\\install_logs\\$APPNAME.log");

###############################################################################################################################
######  This section writes date and time stamp and heading in the log
###############################################################################################################################

print $APPNAME ("************************************************************\n");
print $APPNAME ("This pack will uninstall and install TEST_TOP\n\n") ;

$TDATE = `date \/T`;
$TTIME = `time \/T`;

print $APPNAME ("__________________________________________\n");
print $APPNAME ("Date Started\: $TDATE\n");
print $APPNAME ("Time Started\:  $TTIME\n");
print $APPNAME ("__________________________________________\n\n");

###############################################################################################################################
## SECTION 1: Asset name
###############################################################################################################################
$ASSET = `$rootpath\\system32\\hostname\.exe`;
chomp $ASSET;

###############################################################################################################################
## SECTION x: Variables
###############################################################################################################################

$OSVERSION = `$rootpath\\system32\\reg\.exe QUERY "\\\\$ASSET\\HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion" \/v CurrentBuildNumber`;
$PRODUCTNAME = `$rootpath\\system32\\reg\.exe QUERY "\\\\$ASSET\\HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion" \/v ProductName`;

###############################################################################################################################
## SECTION 2: OS Version
###############################################################################################################################

if ($OSVERSION =~ /1381/) 
    {
        print $APPNAME ("WINDOWS NT MACHINE - $ASSET ...  exiting\n\n");
        print $APPNAME ("Exit Code: 1\n");
        exit 1;
    }
elsif  ($OSVERSION =~ /2195/)
    {
        print $APPNAME ("WINDOWS 2000 MACHINE - $ASSET ...  exiting\n\n");
        print $APPNAME ("Exit Code: 2\n");
        exit 2;
    }
elsif  ($OSVERSION =~ /2600/)
    {
        print $APPNAME ("WINDOWS XP MACHINE - $ASSET .. \n\n");

        $DisplayVersion = `reg query "\\\\$ASSET\\HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\\{B41ED86C\-800F\-48B8\-B3D7\-4AB19DBB62E5\}" \/v DisplayVersion`;

        goto WINXPINSTALL;
    }
elsif (($OSVERSION =~ /76/) || ($PRODUCTNAME =~ /Windows 7/))
    {
        print $APPNAME ("WINDOWS 7 MACHINE - $ASSET\n\n");

        $DisplayVersion = `reg query "\\\\$ASSET\\HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\\{B41ED86C\-800F\-48B8\-B3D7\-4AB19DBB62E5\}" \/v DisplayVersion`;
    }
else 
    {
        print $APPNAME ("Unable to determine OS - $ASSET\n\n");
        print $APPNAME ("Exit Code: 3\n");
        exit 3;
    }
###############################################################################################################################
## Windows 7 ############# Windows 7 ################################### Windows 7 ############################### Windows 7 ##
###############################################################################################################################

if ($DisplayVersion =~ /1.1.10/)
    {
        print $APPNAME ("TEST exist ... uninstalling\n\n");
        goto WIN7UNINSTALLX;
    }
else 
    {
        print $APPNAME ("TEST does not exist ... Installing\n\n");
        goto WIN7INSTALLAPP;
    }

WIN7INSTALLAPP:
###############################################################################################################################
## SECTION 3: Windows 7 Install
###############################################################################################################################

sleep (2);
print $APPNAME ("TEST Installation\n");
print $APPNAME ("____________________________________________________\n\n");

autoflush STDOUT;
autoflush STDERR;

my $etc = File::Spec->catdir($ENV{SYSTEMROOT}, 'system32\drivers\etc');
my $hosts = File::Spec->catfile($etc, 'hosts');
my $backup = File::Spec->catfile($etc, 'hosts_backup.bak');

copy $hosts, $backup or die "Backup failed: $!";
print $APPNAME ("host file backup completed\n\n");

`start \/WAIT msiexec \/i "$rootpath\\MSI\\TEST_TOP\\TEST_TOP\.msi" TRANSFORMS="$rootpath\\MSI\\TEST_TOP\\TEST_TOP_WIN7\.mst" \/l*v "$rootpath\\install\_logs\\TEST\_TOP\_MSIinstall\.log" \/qn`;

$errcode=$?;
if ($errcode == 0) 
    {
        print $APPNAME ("TEST install completed successfully\n\n");
    }
else 
    {
        print $APPNAME ("TEST install failed ... $errcode\n\n");
        print $APPNAME ("Exit Code: 4\n");
        exit 4;
    }
print $APPNAME ("\n\n");
exit 0;


WIN7UNINSTALLX:
###############################################################################################################################
## SECTION 4: Windows 7 Uninstall
###############################################################################################################################

`start \/WAIT msiexec\.exe \/x \{B30ED86C\-800F\-48B8\-B3D7\-4AB19DBB62E5\} \/l*v \"$rootpath\\install\_logs\\TEST\_TOP\_MSIuninstall\.log\" \/qn`;

$errcode=$?;
if ($errcode == 0) 
    {
        print $APPNAME ("TEST uninstall completed successfully\n\n");
        sleep (5);
    }
else 
    {
        print $APPNAME ("TEST uninstall failed ... $errcode\n\n");
        print $APPNAME ("Exit Code: 5\n");
        exit 5;
    }

print $APPNAME ("\n\n");

goto WIN7INSTALLAPP;

###############################################################################################################################
### WINDOWS XP ###################### WINDOWS XP ######################### WINDOWS XP ########################## WINDOWS XP ###
###############################################################################################################################

WINXPINSTALL:

if ($DisplayVersion =~ /1.1.10/)

    {
        print $APPNAME ("TEST exist ... uninstalling\n\n");
        goto WINXPUNINSTALLX;
    }

else 
    {

        print $APPNAME ("TEST does not exist ... Installing\n\n");
        goto WINXPINSTALLAPP;
    }

WINXPINSTALLAPP:
###############################################################################################################################
## SECTION 3: Windows XP Install
###############################################################################################################################

sleep (2);
print $APPNAME ("TEST Installation\n");
print $APPNAME ("____________________________________________________\n\n");

autoflush STDOUT;
autoflush STDERR; 

my $etc = File::Spec->catdir($ENV{SYSTEMROOT}, 'system32\drivers\etc');
my $hosts = File::Spec->catfile($etc, 'hosts');
my $backup = File::Spec->catfile($etc, 'hosts_backup.bak');

copy $hosts, $backup or die "Backup failed: $!";
print $APPNAME ("host file backup completed\n\n");

`start \/WAIT msiexec \/i "$rootpath\\MSI\\TEST\_TOP\\TEST\_TOP\.msi" TRANSFORMS="$rootpath\\MSI\\TEST_TOP\\TEST_TOP_XP\.mst" \/l*v "$rootpath\\install\_logs\\TEST\_TOP\_MSIinstall\.log" \/qn`;

$errcode=$?;
if ($errcode == 0) 
    {
        print $APPNAME ("TEST install completed successfully\n\n");
    }
else 
    {
        print $APPNAME ("TEST install failed ... $errcode\n\n");
        print $APPNAME ("Exit Code: 4\n");
        exit 4;
    }
exit 0;

WINXPUNINSTALLX:
###############################################################################################################################
## SECTION 4: Windows XP Uninstall
###############################################################################################################################

 `start \/WAIT msiexec\.exe \/x \{B30ED86C\-800F\-48B8\-B3D7\-4AB19DBB62E5\} \/l*v \"$rootpath\\install\_logs\\TEST\_TOP\_MSIuninstall\.log\" \/qn`;


$errcode=$?;
if ($errcode == 0) 
    {
        print $APPNAME ("TEST uninstall completed successfully\n\n");
        sleep (5);
    }
else 
    {
        print $APPNAME ("TEST uninstall failed ... $errcode\n\n");
        print $APPNAME ("Exit Code: 5\n");
        exit 5;
    }

print $APPNAME ("\n\n");

goto WINXPINSTALLAPP;
```

Comment: Using the backtick operator in void context isn't wrong, but a poor choice. Backticks are for capturing a command's output. Use [`system`](http://p3rl.org/system) instead.

Answer (score 2):

It is nearly always best to use native Perl operators or modules if possible, rather than shelling out to use comman-line utilities. In this case the [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec) and [`File::Copy`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aCopy) modules are useful. Both of these have been part of the core Perl distribution since the very first releases of Perl v5, and so shouldn't need installing on your system.

In addition, there is no need to delete an existing file for most forms of copy or output: a new file of the same name will be created and the old one silently deleted.

This program does what you need. **Note** that you need to run it with administrator status to be able to write into the system folder where `hosts` is, otherwise the copy will fail - probably with a *No such file or directory* error.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use File::Spec;
use File::Copy 'copy';

autoflush STDOUT;
autoflush STDERR;

my $etc = File::Spec->catdir($ENV{SYSTEMROOT}, 'system32\drivers\etc');
my $hosts = File::Spec->catfile($etc, 'hosts');
my $backup = File::Spec->catfile($etc, 'hosts_backup.bak');

say "From $hosts";
say "To $backup";

copy $hosts, $backup or die "Backup failed: $!";
say 'Success';
```

**output**

```
From C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
To C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts_backup.bak
Success
```

Comment: "It is nearly always best to use native Perl operators or modules if possible" largely because it makes error checking so much easier, which tends to help it happen at all (as in this case).

Comment: `use feature 'say';` should just be `use 5.010;` which has the desired effect but gives a better error if used pre-5.10.

Comment: I prefer `use feature 'say'` in some cases (on SO for example) because it's obvious to the reader what the line does.

Comment: @memowe: Indeed. `use 5.010` is far from being self-documenting

Comment: I've tried this in a script by it's self and it doesn't work. I get a "Can't locate feature.pm in @INC <@INC contains: PERL2EXE_Storage at line 4."

Comment: @LordRazon: Then you are using the very old Perl v5.8 of earlier. It was superseded over five years ago and you really should upgrade. Failing that, remove the `use feature` line and substitute `say` with `print` plus a trailing newline everywhere.